# Do any UK banks have Android apps?

Tags: applications

I'm researching a new current account, and an Android app would be a big bonus for me. None of the big few banks (Lloyds, Natwest, Barclays) seem to have apps. Santander has one but it doesn't work in the UK. Does anyone know of any UK banks which do have an Android app for viewing my balance, making transfers etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick search of the Market, only [Northern Bank](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.northernbank.android.tribank) has anything obvious in there at the moment, and they're not quite one of the really big UK High St banks.

(Barclays have a couple of apps but they're all related to their marketing/sponsorship nothing to do with personal accounts).